# PostgreSQL : How to remove from varchar field starting from special character?(regexp_replace)

Tags: postgresql, regexp-replace

i want to remove everything following first occurence of character 'M' in VARCHAR field (inclusive) .

so `SELECT regexp_replace('The world Mine is mine')`

Should produce : `'The world '`

This is equivalent to

`SELECT left('The world Mine is mine',INSTR('The world Mine is mine','M',1,1)-1)`

But, how to achieve that without `left` and `instr`? Would be glad for responses.

Comment: I would recommend not using SQL for this. Why not pull it into something like python and handle it there?

Comment: I dont want to have external app for this small requirement. That could be handled in SQL (as i show before), i just want to solve that in efficient way.

Comment: I assume you're not doing this in a transactional DB, and if thats the case, which i hope it is, there is no reason you cant write a simple py script to handle this. It's not an 'external app'

Comment: What's wrong with using `left()`  and `instr()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use capturing groups for that:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('The world Mine is mine', '(.*)(M.*)', '\1')
```

returns

```
regexp_replace
--------------
The world
```

---

Regular expressions are quite expensive, using `left()` and `instr()` will most probably be a lot faster.

Comment: You might want this for the regex: `'([^M]*)(M.*)'` as otherwise it does not work if you start the line with a capital 'M' and leave the other Capital 'M' in there.Whatever you do, be sure to test carefully with the 'M' in all positions and in multiple places.  Always expect the unexpected and make sure the regex can handle it.

Comment: P.S.  I tested in Oracle, my apologies if postgresql is different.